# Chrome automatically blocking microphone

Tags: google-chrome, security, https, microphone

I'm trying to test out SpeechRecognition API on my website (which requires microphone use), but because of the policy, Chrome is automatically blocking microphone.

First thing i tried was enabling it through chrome settings, but considering their policies, i was unable to add my website (since it doesn't use ssl encryption yet).

Therefore, i killed all the processes used by Chrome, and opened it with `--disable-web-security`, `--allow-file-access-from-files` and `--user-data-dir` flags. On Mac OS, it looks like this:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --user-data-dir
```

these flags did work, but Chrome is still blocking microphone.

Is there any specific flag that disables this security feature? Or is there any specific data file that contains these permissions?

Comment: I think you may need to go into Chrome itself to allow microphone access for your domain (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/MWtFAKDSAVM), and then open via command.

Comment: @Dallas That was the first thing i tried. But unfortunately chrome does not allow end-users to allow microphone on non-secured sites.

Comment: Did you solve this? Was it happening on a `.local` domain?

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert Nope, couldn't find any solution, tried on both local and external addresses.